# Signature Declare Throws Exception : A method/constructor shouldn't explicitly throw java.lang.Exception

Tags: java

I got this warning on sonar. what is the proper solution to this warning.
My methos is Like:

```
public void abc(A a) throws Exeption {

        dao.pqr(a);
}
```

i got warning to this method in Class.What is proper solution to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should throw the actual Exception(s) if they are known.

If the method you call `throws Exception` and you can't change it there is nothing you can do about it except suppress the warning.

Answer (score 2):

[A method can only throw the exceptions that are relevant to its interface](http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/10_best_practices_with_Exceptions#Relevancy). Exception is the "root" of all exception, so try to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the exception and reconvert it to a Particular exception.

```
 protected RunningJob submitJob(Configuration actionConf) throws RuntimeException {
    .....
    RunningJob rj;
    try{
        rj = super.submitJob(actionConf);
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return rj;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you throw `Exception`, it is unclear as which exceptions the method can throw as `Exception` is very generic.